# Por qué obtengo el error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy intentando resolver un Problema es SPOJ, (dejo el link, dado que es largo de escribirlo acá)

Problema: http://www.spoj.com/problems/AKBAR/

Corro algunos tests que puedo obtener desde acá: http://spojtoolkit.com/history/AKBAR

Obtengo las respuestas satisfactorias en cada test, pero al intentar correrlo en la plataforma Spoj me da el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Podrían darme una mano a encontrar el error. El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente (básicamente realiza una búsqueda BFS sobre un grafo).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class BFS {

    static Scanner parserIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);

    private static List<Integer>[] graph = new List[1000100];

    private static int[] done = new int[1000100];
    private static int[] level = new int[1000100];



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ejecutar();
    }

    static void ejecutar() throws IOException {
        int casos = parserIn.nextInt();
        for (int caso = 0; caso < casos; caso++){
            resolve();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        parserIn.close();
    }

    private static void resolve() {
            int n = parserIn.nextInt();
            int r = parserIn.nextInt();
            int m = parserIn.nextInt();

            Arrays.fill(done,0);
            Arrays.fill(level, -1);

            for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++){
                graph[x] = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {

                int src = parserIn.nextInt();
                int dest = parserIn.nextInt();

                graph[src].add(dest);
                graph[dest].add(src);
            }

            Vector<int[]> soldiers = new Vector<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int number = parserIn.nextInt();
                int strn = parserIn.nextInt();

                int[] data_soldiers = new int[2];
                data_soldiers[0] = number;
                data_soldiers[1] = strn;

                soldiers.add(data_soldiers);
            }
            int flag = 1;

            for (int k = 0; k < soldiers.size(); k++) {
                int[] data_soldiers = soldiers.get(k);

                int src = data_soldiers[0];
                int st = data_soldiers[1];

                LinkedList<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();

                if (done[src] != 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }


                q.push(src);
                done[src] = src;
                level[src] = 0;


                while (!q.isEmpty()) {
                    int u = q.getFirst();
                    q.pop();
                    for (int j = 0; j < graph[u].size(); j++) {
                        int v = graph[u].get(j);
                        if (level[u] + 1 <= st) {
                            if (done[v] != src && done[v] != 0) {
                                flag = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (done[v] == 0){
                                q.push(v);
                                level[v] = level[u] + 1;
                                done[v] = src;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (flag == 0)
                    break;

            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (done[i] == 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag == 0)
                writer.println("No");
            else
                writer.println("Yes");


    }
}
```

Desde ya les agradezco por cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Saludos.

Stack Spoj

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>      at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>      at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>      at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>      at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>      at Main.ejecutar(Main.java:24)
>      at Main.main(Main.java:20)

Localmente no pude reproducirlo (utilizando intellij)

Comment: Cuando usas el teclado le estas dando a un número o a otra tecla que no se puede "parsear" a `Integer`?

Comment: No, la plataforma spoj hace el ingreso de datos de forma automática y no puedo ver que ingresa.

Comment: Si no me equivoco `System.in` se refiere a la entrada por consola. No conozco esa plataforma pero deberás averiguar el `InputStream` que debes usar en vez de `System.in`

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` es la entrada de teclado no la entrada de la plataforma Spoj. Lo siguiente es una cita de [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

> public static final InputStream in :
>   The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

Comment: Está perfecto, pero la plataforma te deja el input en System.in es correcto que lo lea desde ahí.

Comment: ¿Pero tendrás que configurarlo para que eso sea así no? ¿Puedes pasarme un enlace a la documentación de esa plataforma para echarle un vistazo?

Comment: Esto es como una guía para los usuarios, es el mismo estilo de plataformas de Hackerrank: http://www.spoj.com/tutorials/USERS/

Comment: Debes usar `Parser in = new Parser(System.in);` en lugar de `Scanner parserIn = new Scanner(System.in);`. Parser es una clase que debe permitirte usar los datos de la plataforma. El enlace al código esta en este proyecto de Github: https://github.com/darrensun/OJ-Solutions/blob/master/src/com/darrensun/spoj/facefrnd/Main.java

Comment: No, en realidad no. Si miras lo que me enviaste, la clase Parser está definida ahí dentro https://github.com/darrensun/OJ-Solutions/blob/master/src/com/darrensun/spoj/facefrnd/Main.java#L47

Comment: Claro que esta definida dentro, pero lo que te estoy diciendo es que debes usarla en vez de `Scanner` que es lo que estas usando y por eso no funciona. Te puse el enlace por si no tienes el código de `Parser`

Comment: Según estoy leyendo en los foros para Java, sí se puede usar la clase `Scanner` sin problema. Revisar [aquí](http://discuss.spoj.com/t/solution-to-test-in-java/59). Creo que el problema es porque la clase no se llama `Main`.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n me da este error usando ese Parser (que para mí es lo mismo o muy parecido) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65536
 at Main$Parser.read(Main.java:178)
 at Main$Parser.nextInt(Main.java:145)
 at Main.ejecutar(Main.java:28)
 at Main.main(Main.java:22)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza cuándo lo corro en spoj hago la modificación del nombre de la clase.

Comment: @baezjm Ok, creo que ya encontré el problema. No tiene nada que ver con `System.in` ni eso. El problema parece estar en tu código, en algún momento intentas leer un `int` cuando no lo hay. Ahora, ¿por qué puede suceder esto? Sería cosa de revisar a detalle en qué momento se cae la aplicación. Si no, puedes cambiar de `Scanner` a `BufferedReader`, aumentará el código para la lectura de datos pero resolverá tu situación.

Comment: Prueba con un test corto para no salirte del `BUFFER_SIZE` o termina la ejecución cuando llegue la variable `bufferPointer` al tamaño de `BUFFER_SIZE`. Yo creo que el fallo está en la línea `return buffer[bufferPointer++];`. Si así no te diera error ya sabremos por lo que es.

Comment: El tema es ese, cuando lo pruebo con algo corto (localmente) funciona, pero después spoj corre test gigantes (que no puedo maenejar) y ahí está dando el error.

Comment: En el enlace que puso @Luiggi Mendoza habla de una limitación de java por su i/o. Dice que es lento y que tiene una limitación de 50000. En nuestro caso es mayor y peta. Habla de solucionarlo con unas librerías externas. Deberías leerlo ya que sabes cual es el fallo para intentar otra solución.

Comment: @baezjm quizás lo que debas hacer es procesar los bytes directamente desde `System.in` tal como se muestra en [este ejemplo para el ICPC](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/data/p100.java.html)

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` se lanza cuando tratas de acceder a un elemento de una secuencia que no existe. En el caso que muestras el problema es que estás llamando `nextInt` del `Scanner` cuando ya no tienes más datos de entrada.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está al llamar al Scanner para leer un número entero cuando tienes 3 números en una misma línea.

La opción sería leer la línea completa, dividir y parsear los números:

```
String[] nrm = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
n = Integer.parseInt(nrm[0]);
r = Integer.parseInt(nrm[1]);
m = Integer.parseInt(nrm[2]);
```

Saludos!